# Nginx include in location working for whole config

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

Nginx config in project I'm working on is split in different files

```
a.conf 

location a 
{

}

b.conf

location b 
{
  include c.conf
}

c.conf 

location ~ \.php$ {return 404}
```

when I run nginx -T I get this

```
#configuration file a.conf        
location a {}

#configuration file b.conf       
location b 
{
  include c.conf
}

#configuration file c.conf            
location ~ \.php$ {return 404}
```

Does last line mean, that `location ~ \.php$ {return 404}` will work for every location on server? And I will get 404 response on `{host}/a.php`, `{host}/b.php` etc.? Or it will work only for `{host}/b.php`?

Can I use `nginx -T` command in that case for reviewing in what order nginx will check locations?

Comment: Nginx will select a location to process a request according the rules defined by [How Nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) and [the location directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).

Comment: Please add the real config, for config location match rule has many types. Without the actually, you issue is hard to explain.